# How to call didChangeSection to force update of sections in swift

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift2, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been having a problem with CoreData and Sections from related entities. To show my issue, I have made as simple as possible version of my app. This is the link to the file if you'd like to download it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7gcpu7qq2mnrye/Sample%20List%20App.zip?dl=0

It's just a tableview, and hitting the plus button adds in a new item where the the quantity is 1, the name is 1, and the section is 1. Then clicking the cell increments them all. You can see that both the name and quantity are updating just fine, but the section never updates. This seems to be because the frc isn't tracking the change in the Section Table, but doesn't have a problem with the catalog or item table. When I quit the app and then start it up again, then the sections load correctly. Here are my current entities and relationships (of simple app)

[image]

Below is the code from the tableviewcontroller.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - Constants and Variables

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// MARK: - App loading Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Outlets and Actions

@IBAction func addItemPress(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: self.moc)
    let item = Items(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.moc)

    item.qty = 1

    entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Catalog", inManagedObjectContext: self.moc)
    let catalog = Catalog(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.moc)

    catalog.name = 1

    var section: Sections?
    if (checkSectionName(0, moc: self.moc) == false) {
        entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Sections", inManagedObjectContext: self.moc)
        section = Sections(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.moc)

        section!.section = 1
    } else {
        section = returnSection(0, moc: self.moc)
    }

    item.catalog = catalog
    item.catalog!.sections = section

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("New item save failed")
    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let item: Items = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items

    cell.nameLbl.text = "Item #\(item.catalog!.name!)"
    cell.qtyLbl.text = "Qty: \(item.qty!.stringValue)"

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return "Section \(currentSection.name)"
    }

    return nil
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let item: Items = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items
    var qty: Int = Int(item.qty!)
    qty = qty + 1

    item.qty = qty

    var name: Int = Int(item.catalog!.name!)
    name = name + 1

    item.catalog!.name = name

    var sec: Int = Int(item.catalog!.sections!.section!)
    sec = sec + 1

    var section: Sections?
    if (checkSectionName(sec, moc: self.moc) == false) {
        let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Sections", inManagedObjectContext: self.moc)
        section = Sections(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.moc)

        section!.section = sec
    } else {
        section = returnSection(sec, moc: self.moc)
    }

    item.catalog!.sections = section

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Edit item save failed")
    }

}

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "catalog.sections.section", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "catalog.name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "catalog.sections.section" , cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}

func checkSectionName(sectionName: NSNumber, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {

    var exists: Bool = false

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sections")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "section == %@", sectionName)
    fetchReq.predicate = pred

    do {
        let check = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq)
        for rec in check {
            if let name = rec.valueForKey("section") {
                if (name as! NSNumber == sectionName) {
                    exists = true
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed fetching records when checking if List name already exists")
    }

    return exists

}

func returnSection(sectionName: NSNumber, moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Sections {

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sections")
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "section == %@", sectionName)
    fetchReq.predicate = pred

    do {
        let check = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq)
        return check.first! as! Sections
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed fetching records to return section")
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with this a little, it seems the `didChangeSection` is only fired if the first relationship named in the `sectionNameKeyPath` is directly modified (ie. in this case, if you create a new `Catalog` linked to the correct section, and set `item.catalog = newCatalog`).  But I think that is too convoluted as a work-around.

One solution would be to change your FRC to fetch the `Catalog` objects instead of `Items`.  Since they map one-one, the table view should retain the same structure.  The key changes are:

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Catalog")
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sections.section", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2]

    return fetchRequest
}
```

and

```
func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "sections.section" , cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}
```

Then modify the references to `frc` to reflect this change:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let catalog: Catalog = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Catalog

    cell.nameLbl.text = "Item #\(catalog.name!)"
    cell.qtyLbl.text = "Qty: \(catalog.items.qty!.stringValue)"

    return cell
}
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let catalog: Catalog = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Catalog

    var qty: Int = Int(catalog.items.qty!)
    qty = qty + 1    
    catalog.items.qty = qty

    var name: Int = Int(catalog.name!)
    name = name + 1
    catalog.name = name

    var sec: Int = Int(catalog.sections.section!)
    sec = sec + 1
    var section: Sections?
    if (checkSectionName(sec, moc: self.moc) == false) {
        let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Sections", inManagedObjectContext: self.moc)
        section = Sections(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.moc)

        section!.section = sec
    } else {
        section = returnSection(sec, moc: self.moc)
    }

    catalog.sections = section

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Edit item save failed")
    }

}
```

Because you are directly modifying the `sections` property of the `catalog` object, this will trigger the `didChangeSection` method.

Comment: It's a bit of an ugly solution, which I realise might not translate well from the example cited in your question to your real world problem.  I hope it helps.

Comment: That is a really good idea! I'll give it a shot when I get home tonight and hook you up with the bounty if it does work. Thank you

Comment: LOL, you should post on this one too, that is where the bounty is at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328774/section-update-event-not-being-called-from-related-entity-in-swift

Comment: I just tried adding it into the Sample List App. And its definitely trying to work, but now I get a strange error message I've never gotten before. When I increment, didChangeSection throws `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert` which works fine, but then it gets called again and throws `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete` which causes an error. I'll fit as much as I can: `An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  cannot move a row from a deleted section (1) with userInfo (null)` I've never seen that before... any ideas?

Comment: Found the problem, I had seen code online that suggested using `self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)` instead of `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` then `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` inside of `didChangeObject` when the `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move` type is called. Turns out that doesn't work. Switched it back and it works. I'm pretty sure this will scale up to my bigger full app, so I'll give it a shot. (Please please comment on the other post, I'd really really like to give you the bounty if this works!)

Comment: @JasonBrady I wasn't aware of the bounty!  I've added my answer to the other question.  To avoid duplication it might be appropriate to delete this question.